# Are MacBooks Laptops, Notebooks or Netbooks

Tags: macbook-pro

Are MacBooks (not just the retina MacBook) Laptops, Notebooks or Netbooks?

This is what I think.

- Macbook Pro - Laptop (High power and a lot of I/Os
- MacBook Air - NoteBook (Medium power and a few I/Os
- MacBook - Netbook (Low power and 1 I/O

Am I right or wrong?
If I am wrong could someone explain to me why?

Comment: They are all Laptop (something you can use on your lap). The subdivisions are the NoteBook and the Netbook came later identifying specific designs and purpose of a Laptop. Netbook was a form of a laptop as inexpensive, light-weight, energy-efficient device, especially suited for wireless communication and Internet access.

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: good question! who know why !

Comment: That would be a good question to ask on meta for a better explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're all just marketing terms.

Laptop - generic, applies to anything with a screen attached on a hinge
The most basic distinction from a non-portable Desktop, traditionally with a separate monitor & keyboard.

Notebook - initially referred to HP laptops

Netbook - originally very low-end devices, powered by the Intel Atom, some running Windows, some on unix

The lines have blurred over the years - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laptop#Traditional_laptop) has an article on it, but I'd still say most of the distinctions are really artificial

The 'book' part is the only consistency - implying it can only be a 'book' if it's roughly a standard clamshell design, with a screen & keyboard on the inside when closed.

Comment: Ok, So are all of the MacBooks Notebooks? Or is the 12" MacBook a Netbook due to the 1.1GHz Core-M processor?

Comment: They's all just marketing terms - none of them are anything other than a portable personal computer. A MacBook is a MacBook, just as an HP Notebook is a notebook

Comment: Just looked at the MacBook launch on the Apple event. Tim Cook was talking about the Notebook

Comment: if Tim Cook was talking about notebooks, that's more proof than you'd need that the lines are so blurred even the manufacturer no longer is certain of the distinction

Comment: Ive also heard other people calling MacBooks Notebooks. Is it really that blurred? Ive also seen people on the internet saying the 12" MacBook is a Netbook. Not saying your wrong. Just saying what i've seen and heard.

Comment: No-one has made anything actually defined as a netbook since 2012 according to the Wikipedia article I posted [probably because they were barely powerful enough to load a webpage & so the term has been 'poisoned'. It's all just hype.

Comment: Ok. Do you mean 2012 and not 1012. Didn't think we had laptop in those days let alone desktop computers! :P

Answer (score 2):

Only two things I had to add here:
The official [Apple Style Guide](https://help.apple.com/asg/mac/2013/ASG_2013.pdf) has the following:

> **laptop computer**
>
> Avoid in favor of portable computer, which is preferred, or notebook
>   computer. See also **portable computer, notebook computer, laptop**
>   **computer**."

And anecdotally, even before PowerBooks transitioned to the notoriously hot-running MacBook Pro during the Intel transition, Genius Bar folklore I overheard implied that even though it was a portable, the computer was was not to be used on your lap, ergo any other naming besides 'laptop'...

Comment: I also heard people saying of not having them on your lap but to have a lap stand/table or use it on the desk (I pay no notice!).